# Why can't I get the value of an ion-radio using the word value?

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to fire a function with the option selected without having to click a confirmation button. So I'm using the provided event "ionSelect". But when I try to access the parameter at the component it says 'undefined'. I started trying random things and "$event" worked. Sadly I don't know why, any explanation of this sorcery?

NOT WORKING

```
<ion-radio value="1" (ionSelect)="checkMyOption(value)"></ion-radio>
```

WORKING

```
<ion-radio value="1" (ionSelect)="checkMyOption($event)"></ion-radio>
```

Comment: That's because, when you say `checkMyOption(value)`, angular starts looking for a variable named 'value' for given component, which isn't available. Framework doesn't understand that the `value` here is `ion-radio`'s value. If you want to pass the element's value , you can try `<ion-radio #radioId value="1" (ionSelect)="checkMyOption(radioId?.value)"></ion-radio>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no variable in your exported class in `.ts` file, named as `value`. The `value` in `<ion-radio value="1">` is a property of that `ion-radio` tag.

But, `$event` is an actual event data which is created when you select that particular `<ion-radio>` option.